# How do I interpret the +1 offset in free -m on Linux terminal console?

Tags: command-line, ram, free

Well, I made a mistake with my first post of this question and I'm pretty sure that I've figured this problem out; however, I love to get feedback from other programmers who may have more direct expertise with issues.

I landed on this page because I am researching the best descriptive methods for explaining the output that `sudo free -m` command displays in the Ubuntu/Linux terminal.  I have a problem with interpreting this output [free -m on Ubuntu/Linux terminal console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HDNZ.png).

The rows and columns are self-explanatory enough for the most part; however, what is irritating me is that in every example that I analyzed the free = used(memory) - total- buffer - cache and the used = total - free - buffer - cache; the result is always offset by +1 megabyte greater than the system report for free (memory).

This is due to the indexing memory addresses where the counts begin at 0, right? Or is it a swap issue, an availability issue, or just some anomaly that is treated as negligible?

Comment: It is not necessary to use sudo to run free.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this fact. :) Thank you for noting it but this is for an Operating System Architecture course;  the use of 'sudo' is mostly demonstrative, as sudo is the superuser and/or system administrative (BSD System Manager's) command that shows that we are aware of how to handle administrative tasks.

Comment: Excessive use of sudo is a very bad habit.  When it becomes reflexive to just prefix everything with sudo, you will eventually run something that will break things when it would have been fine in a user context.  Saying "but this is for a class" makes it worse, because now you are using bad examples to teach.

Answer (score 1):

The `-m` option of free rounds the numbers to 1M.  So the discrepancy is almost certainly round off error.  Recheck the numbers without `-m`

Comment: Thank you user10489; that definitely clarified the problem. I am going to reference your comment in my paper BTW...